# Is there any specific way to check if there's only one letter in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to find a regex pattern that checks if there's one letter in between the space.

For example: John A Doe
I want to capture only John Doe (without A) but there's 50/50 chance that the data will not contain middle initials.

I made this pattern `([A-z]* [A-z] [A-z]*|[A-z]* [A-z]*)` but it captures also the middle one.

I'm sorry for the vague title cause I'm really confused rn.

Edit: I forgot about the [A-z] captures upto 122 in ascii table. I replaced it with \w as well.

Comment: If you stop asking for a regex to parse a Proper Name and make it for a block of letters separated by an optional middle group of letters following a block of letters. It would be feasible. Regex cannot parse names, never could nor will. Invariably, you will be dissapointed and it will never be a solution you are looking for. Google NLP.

Comment: You can't "unmatch"  a part of a string in the middle of a capture. So, either use two groups, and then concatenate them, or use `Regex.Replace` to capture what you need and use backreferences in the replacement to build the necessary result. Moreover, [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). So, `Regex.Replace(text, @"(\p{L}+)(?:\s+\p{L})?\s+(\p{L}+)", "$1 $2")` might come close to what can work for you.

Comment: Why this specific range [A-z] (Do you remember the ASCII table?)? What are you actually building? What about other names that contain the myriads of world Unicode characters?

Comment: Note, A-z is not reliable here.. yes it does do upper and lower letters but it also matches a few more like `[ ]` and others - in the ascii table, `a` does not follow immediately on from `Z`, you might prefer   `a-zA-Z`

Comment: Roughly `[A-z]` resolves to `[a-zA-Z\\\[\]-\`]` if interested.

Comment: oh yeah, I remembered about the ascii table. Thanks! I'll need a new pattern as well.

Comment: Concatenating strings is a good idea. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yet still,  example `For example: John A Doe` is not anything language related ? 3 billion different names, yet John XYZ Doe is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps code like:

```
var m = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<f>[a-z]+)( [a-z])? (?<l>[a-z]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["f"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["l"].Value);
```

You'll need to capture the first and last names separately and stick them back together later